# Let $G$ be a group and $m \in G$, $K$ be a subgroup and $m * m \in K$. Is it always true that $m \in K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to use this in another proof, but I think it might be false and I'm out of ideas to prove it.

Comment: You're right, I've edited my post right away. Dumb mistake.

Comment: No. $K$ can be trivial, and $m$ can be element of order $2$.

Comment: No. In the integers modulo $2$ we have $1+1 = 0$ in the subgroup $K$ consisting only of $0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No way.  In the group $\mathbb{Z}$ consider the subgroup $E$ of evens. Then $1+1 \in E$ but $1 \notin E$.

Comment: You're right, I'm glad I didn't try to use this. I'll accept your answer as soon as possible. Very silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

No: Let $K=\mathbb{Q}^*$ and $G = \mathbb{R}^*$. Then $\sqrt{2}*\sqrt{2}\in K$ but $\sqrt{2}\notin K$.

Comment: The reals aren't a group under multiplication.

Comment: Now we're talking.  Good example.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $G=\mathbb Z, K=2 \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.

Consider the rationals as a subgroup of real numbers.

$\sqrt 5 \times \sqrt 5 $ is in the subgroup but $ \sqrt 5$ is not.